# twilio receive sms without responding back

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

Good Day,

How do I properly receive an SMS on my web app using twilio without responding back to the sender.

I read about this.. https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134127-Receive-SMS-messages-without-Responding but I need to use the webhook to send the sms to my webapplication too, if I do receive it without setting a response, It will generate an Error - 11200 (HTTP retrieval failure) how do I prevent this? also by setting up respones.

my code is

```
var resp = new twilio.twiml.MessagingResponse();
resp.message('<Response></Response>');
                      res.writeHead(200, {
                        'Content-Type':'text/xml'
                      });
                      res.end(resp.toString());
```

sadly this one sends `<Response></Response>` to the sender instead.. im using nodejs by the way.. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Those who are finding this in 2021,

If you need to just recieve message from twilio and not send any message to user then you can use this code.

```
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end();
```

For more refer this doc,
[Receive SMS and MMS Messages without Responding](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223134127-Receive-SMS-and-MMS-Messages-without-Responding)

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried yet but I think if you comment out this line:

`// resp.message("<Response></Response>");`

no message will be sent.

---

**Update after reading Phil's comment:**

This: `resp.message('<Response></Response>');`

is equivalent with sending the folowing XML to Twilio:

```
<Response>
  <Response></Response>
</Response>
```

in which case the sender will receive a message like: `<Response></Response>`

If you comment out the line

`// resp.message("<Response></Response>");`

or if you do `resp.message("");`

is equivalent with sending the folowing XML to Twilio:

`<Response />`

in which case no message will be sent to the sender.

Comment: ahh thanks for the suggestion sir.. I was thinking resp.message(''); but I guess it also send blank sms. yeah maybe yours will work.. I'll give it a try !