# Proper way to NOT send a reply back from webhook

Tags: twilio

I have setup a webhook and everything is working properly, however iam used to using a long number where STOP is handled automatically, but now I have a short code where we have to handle STOP ourselves. This isnt an issue on sending a message as I can check with my 'blacklist' numbers before sending the message.  My question is in the Reply webhook, what is the best way or standard way to NOT send the reply message.

Below is twilios sample code (i added the comment where i would check if they are black listed)

```
 public class SmsController : TwilioController
    {
        public TwiMLResult Index(SmsRequest incomingMessage)
        {
            var messagingResponse = new MessagingResponse();

            // check for phone number in blacklist to NOT SEND
            messagingResponse.Message("The copy cat says: " +
                                      incomingMessage.Body);

            return TwiML(messagingResponse);
        }
    }
```

If the number is blacklisted and i dont want to send the reply how do I "gracefully" not reply to them as this example takes a TwiMLResult and message response. Do i just set the message to an empty string ? do I return null? Any thoughts ? Thank you !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443473/twilio-receive-sms-without-responding-back/47443962#47443962

Comment: Thanks @AlexBaban ! i was thinking just passing in an empty string, but was curious if there was like a "right" way to do it according to twilio (maybe this is the right way), but if it works it works ! Thanks !